# Postgres: Querying most recent 2 records for a user with created_at time differing by < 1 second?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
create table Account(
  userId: INT NOT NULL,
  status: TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at: TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

A `userId` can have multiple accounts and status can be either `ACTIVE` or `CANCELLED`. I want the most recent account to be `ACTIVE` and a user to have only 1 `ACTIVE account`. Currently there are `userIds` that have an `ACTIVE` account but the latest account for the user is `CANCELLED` and these are the ones I want to identify.

Is there a query for finding the 2 most recent accounts (by `created_at` where one is ACTIVE and the other is CANCELLED (or any other text really).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get last two accounts using `row_number()`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT *,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a1.userid
                                       ORDER BY a1.created_at DESC) rn
                    FROM account a1) a2
       WHERE a2.rn <= 2;
```

But this would also return single accounts (per user). If you don't want that join a subquery getting the number of accounts for every user and check if that count is >= 2.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT *,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a1.userid
                                       ORDER BY a1.created_at DESC) rn
                    FROM account a1) a2
            INNER JOIN (SELECT a3.userid,
                               count(*) c
                               FROM account a3
                               GROUP BY a3.userid) a4
                       ON a4.userid = a2.userid                
       WHERE a2.rn <= 2
             AND a4.c >= 2;
```

But you can also directly identify the accounts in question. Use a subquery with a `GROUP BY userid` to get the `max(created_at)` for every user. `INNER JOIN` that result to the accounts and filter `WHERE status = 'CANCELLED'`. Use an `EXISTS` to check if that user ever had an `'ACTIVE'` account. Join that again to get all the accounts for such users.

```
SELECT *
       FROM account a1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT a2.userid
                               FROM account a2
                                    INNER JOIN (SELECT a3.user_id,
                                                       max(a3.created_at) created_at
                                                       FROM account a3
                                                       GROUP BY a3.userid) a4
                                               ON a4.userid = a2.user_id
                                                  AND a4.created_at = a3.created_at
                               WHERE a1.status = 'CANCELLED'
                                     AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                        FROM account a5
                                                        WHERE a5.userid = a1.userid
                                                              AND a5.status = 'ACTIVE')) a6
                       ON a6.userid = a1.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lag()` and `distinct on` to get the most recent status:

```
select distinct on (user_id) a.*
from (select a.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as prev_status
      from account a
     ) a
order by user_id, created_at desc;
```

If you want the ones that are cancelled but active immediately before, use a subquery:

```
select a.*
from (select distinct on (user_id) a.*
      from (select a.*,
                   lag(status) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as prev_status
            from account a
           ) a
      order by user_id, created_at desc
     ) a
where status = 'CANCELLED' and prev_status = 'ACTIVE'
```